# Dynamic creation of host groups in zabbix for a period of time

Tags: php, c, api, zabbix

Can zabbix be used to create host groups for a period of time adding hosts dynamically and removing hosts after period of time?

Answer (score 0):

No, Zabbix itself cannot do this (to my knowledge). But you can use the [API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/api/api) and feed it from some other config management or network discovery system.

There's also [Zabbix' network discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/discovery/network_discovery), which can add hosts on your local network. But I guess you're more talking about cloud networks, where you can't discover hosts on a network level, don't you?

Comment: Thanks - I've seen the APIs, I wanted to check if it is possible to do it without API integration. Not cloud networks, I'm talking about moving devices that come together to form a network in a particular context say for eg. devices on train on a route. This makes the network work only for the span of routes. I've looked at network discovery support but I'm not sure if I'd like to fping large subnets and the IP schema isn't in my control. I also wanted to check out if LLDP can be used with zabbix, any ideas on that?

Comment: LLDP has to be supported by the devices, doesn't it? Zabbix discovery can scan IP ranges. So in this case it might be possible to just add the devices that join your network (if they get an IP from your DHCP? But then you could even take this information as source of truth and add devices after they requested an IP). Haven't a clear solution in mind, sorry. Think you have to do some programming.

Comment: Yes LLDP has to be supported on devices but LLDP data is exposed through standard MIBs and I thought if a device supports it then it might be possible to discover neighbours through LLDP specific OIDs in Zabbix. This will avoid scanning large subnets I think.